# sql query encoding changed after SSIS package deploy

Tags: ssis

I use VS2015 community edition to create SSIS packages and MS Sql Server 2016 (13.0.4199.0) run them.

In SSIS package I have OLE DB Source that reads data from MS Sql Server.
In query there is "Ö" and "Ä" characters and everything works fine when I run package in Visual Studio but when I deploy package to SSIS Catalog and run either package itself or with Agent job result is not same.

Visual Studio run gives me 732 rows but run deployed package gives me 527 rows.

I ran Profiler and noticed that sql query "Ö" changed to "Ä-" and "Ä" changed to "Ä,,".

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: you probably need to check the database collation of the deployed database compared to your local instance.

Comment: im working with visual studio in same server than target database is. i have try to find visual studio settings that might be related to this issue but have not found anything. database collation for SSISDB is same that we have multiple other servers that doesn't have this problem.